# Advection reaction equation is solved by projection of solution of continuity equation

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, gradient-flows, transport-equation, wasserstein

> Suppose an [absolutely continuous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Properties_of_these_generalizations) $\mu \colon (0, \infty) \to P_2(\Omega)$, where $P_2$ is the [Wasserstein-2-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Definition), fulfils the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Differential_form)
> $$ \label{eq:CE} \tag{CE}
> \partial_t \mu_t = \text{div}(\mu_t g_{\mathfrak h \mu_t})
> $$
> for almost all $t > 0$ in the [weak sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation#Example_2:_Poisson%27s_equation), where $\Omega := \Theta \times \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, $\Theta$ is a compact connected [Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Definition) [without boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary) and
> $$
> g_{v} \colon \Omega \to T \Omega, \qquad (r, \theta)
> \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
>             2 \alpha r \cdot J_{v}'(\theta) \\
>             \beta \cdot \nabla J_{v}'(\theta)
>         \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R \times T_{\theta} \Theta
> $$
> for some fixed $\alpha, \beta > 0$ and $v \in M_+(\Theta)$ is a finite non-negative [Radon measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure) on $\Theta$ and $J_v' \colon \Theta \to \mathbb R$ is [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Differentiable_functions).
> Show that (this is Proposition 2.1 in [Lenaic Chizat](http://lchizat.github.io/)'s [*Sparse optimization on measures with overparametrized gradient descent*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10300)) $v_t := \mathfrak h \mu_t$ fufills
> $$ \label{eq:advec} \tag{$\ddagger$}
> \partial_t v_t = -4 \alpha v_t J_{v_t}' + \beta \cdot \text{div}(v_t \nabla J_{v_t}')
> $$
> in [the weak sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation#Example_2:_Poisson%27s_equation) for almost every $t > 0$, where $\mathfrak h \colon P_2(\Omega) \to M_+(\Theta)$ is defined via
> $$ \label{eq:h} \tag{$\dagger$}
> \int_{\Theta} \psi(\theta) \, \text{d}(\mathfrak h \mu)(\theta)
> = \int_{\Omega} \psi(\theta) r^2 \, \text{d}\mu(\theta, r)
> \qquad \forall \psi \in \mathcal C(\Theta; \mathbb R).
> $$
> The [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Definition) on $\Omega$ is
> $$ \label{eq:omega} \tag{$\star$}
> \langle (r_1, \partial \theta_1), (r_2, \partial \theta_2) \rangle_{(r, \theta)} := \frac{1}{\alpha} r_1 r_2 + \frac{r^2}{\beta} \langle \partial \theta_1, \partial \theta_2 \rangle_{\theta}
> $$
> for $x = (r, \theta) \in \Omega$ and $(r_1, \partial \theta_1), (r_2, \partial \theta_2) \in T_x \Omega \cong \mathbb R \times T_{\theta} \Theta$.

**My attempts.**
Let $\xi \colon \Theta \to \mathbb R$ be [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Differentiable_functions).
Then for almost all $t > 0$
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \int_{\Theta} \xi(\theta) \, \text{d}v_t(\theta)
& \overset{\eqref{eq:h}}{\underset{v_t=\mathfrak h \mu_t}{=}} \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \int_{\Omega} \xi(\theta) r^2 \, \text{d}\mu_t(\theta, r) \\
& \overset{\eqref{eq:CE}}{=} - \int_{\Omega} \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} \nabla \xi(\theta) \\ 2 r \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \beta \cdot \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta) \\ 2 \alpha r \cdot J_{v_t}'(\theta) \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle_{(\theta, r)} \, \text{d}\mu_t(\theta, r) \\
&\overset{\eqref{eq:omega}}{=} - \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\alpha} (2 r) \cdot 2 \alpha r \cdot J_{v_t}'(\theta) + \frac{r^2}{\beta} \beta \langle \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta), \nabla \xi(\theta) \rangle_{\theta} \, \text{d}\mu_t(\theta, r) \\
& = - \int_{\Omega}  r^2 \cdot \left( 4 J_{v_t}'(\theta) + \langle \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta), \nabla \xi(\theta) \rangle_{\theta}\right) \, \text{d}\mu_t(\theta, r) \\
& \overset{\eqref{eq:h}}{\underset{v_t=\mathfrak h \mu_t}{=}} - \int_{\Theta} 4 J_{v_t}'(\theta) + \langle \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta), \nabla \xi(\theta) \rangle_{\theta} \, \text{d}v_t(\theta),
\end{align}
because the [weak formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation#Example_2:_Poisson%27s_equation) of \eqref{eq:CE} is
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \int_{\Omega} \psi(x) \, \text{d}\mu_t(x)
= - \int_{\Omega} \langle \nabla \psi(x), g_{\mathfrak{h} \mu_t}(x) \rangle_{x} \, \text{d}\mu_t(x)
$$
for all [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Differentiable_functions) maps $\psi \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$.

But this doesn't look like the weak formulation of \eqref{eq:advec}, which should be something like
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \int_{\Theta} \xi(\theta) \, \text{d}v_t(\theta)
= - \int_{\Theta} 4 \alpha \xi(\theta) J_{v_t}'(\theta) + \beta \langle \nabla \xi(\theta), \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta) \rangle_{\theta} \, \text{d}v_t(\theta),
$$
because the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are missing.
Is my calculation wrong (I am particularly sure about the computation of the gradient of $\xi(\theta) \cdot r^2$) or did I compute the [weak formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation#Example_2:_Poisson%27s_equation) of \eqref{eq:advec} wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weak formulation is correct, the mistake is in the computation of the gradient of $\psi(\theta, r) := \xi(\theta) r^2$, which depends on the metric on $\Omega$ and is given by (for a derivation see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4660140/545914)) $$\nabla \psi(\theta, r) = (\beta \nabla \xi(\theta), 2 \alpha r\xi(\theta)\big).$$

Hence the correct computation is
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \int_{\Theta} \xi(\theta) \, \text{d}v_t(\theta)
& \overset{(\dagger)}{\underset{v_t=\mathfrak h \mu_t}{=}} \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \int_{\Omega} \xi(\theta) r^2 \, \text{d}\mu_t(\theta, r) \\
& \overset{\text{(CE)}}{=} - \int_{\Omega} \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} \beta \nabla \xi(\theta) \\ 2 \alpha r \xi(\theta)\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \beta \cdot \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta) \\ 2 \alpha r \cdot J_{v_t}'(\theta) \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle_{(\theta, r)} \, \text{d}\mu_t(\theta, r) \\
&\overset{(\star)}{=} - \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\alpha} \xi(\theta) (2 r) \cdot 2 \alpha^2 r \cdot J_{v_t}'(\theta) + \frac{r^2}{\beta} \beta^2 \langle \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta), \nabla \xi(\theta) \rangle_{\theta} \, \text{d}\mu_t(\theta, r) \\
& = - \int_{\Omega}  r^2 \cdot \left( 4 \alpha \xi(\theta) J_{v_t}'(\theta) + \beta \langle \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta), \nabla \xi(\theta) \rangle_{\theta}\right) \, \text{d}\mu_t(\theta, r) \\
& \overset{(\dagger)}{\underset{v_t=\mathfrak h \mu_t}{=}} - \int_{\Theta} 4 \alpha \xi(\theta) J_{v_t}'(\theta) + \beta\langle \nabla J_{v_t}'(\theta), \nabla \xi(\theta) \rangle_{\theta} \, \text{d}v_t(\theta),
\end{align}
for almost all $t > 0$, as desired.